# Closing Soft Keyboard on Home Button Press

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-alertdialog, android-homebutton

So I have an app with a custom AlertDialog that has an Ok and Cancel button, and an EditText Object. When I click on the 'Name of Workout' button, the AlertDialog and the soft Keyboard open. At this point, with the AlertDialog open and the soft Keyboard displayed, if the user decides to hit the home key, the app closes, but the soft keyboard is still displayed. How would I close the soft Keyboard along with the entire app from this point? Here is my code:

```
package com.example.test_project;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class NewWorkout extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private TextView mDateDisplay;
private Button mPickDate;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

private TextView mTimeDisplay;
private Button mTimePicker1;
private int hour;
private int minute;
private String zone;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 99;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_workout);
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // capture our View elements
    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateOfWorkoutTextView);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateOfWorkoutButton);
    mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutTextView);
    mTimePicker1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutButton);


    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    final Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = t.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = t.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //set the current time into the textview



    mTimePicker1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

}

// updates the date in the TextView
private void updateDisplay() {
        StringBuilder string1 = new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" ");
    mDateDisplay.setText(string1);
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
         new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
         hour = selectedHour;
         minute = selectedMinute;
         updateTimeDisplay();
     }
 };

//set current time into textView
private void updateTimeDisplay() {
     if(hour > 12){
         hour -= 12;
         zone = "PM";
     }
     else
         zone = "AM";

     if(minute >= 10){
     mTimeDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour)
                .append(":").append(minute).append(" ").append(zone));
     }
     else
         mTimeDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour)
                .append(":").append("0").append(minute).append(" ").append(zone));
 }

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, false);
    }
    return null;
}


public void nameOfWorkout(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Enter a Name for This Workout");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    // Prepping the soft keyboard to open with the AlertDialog
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      String value = input.getText().toString();
      TextView edit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameOfWorkoutTextView);
      edit.setText(value);
      imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN, 0);
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN, 0);
      }
    });
        //alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    alert.show();

    //Causing the soft keyboard to open with the AlertDialog
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}

}
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
package com.example.test_project;

import java.util.Calendar;

import com.example.test_project.R.string;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class NewWorkout extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private TextView mDateDisplay;
private Button mPickDate;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

private TextView mTimeDisplay;
private Button mTimePicker1;
private int hour;
private int minute;
private String zone;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 99;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_workout);
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // capture our View elements
    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateOfWorkoutTextView);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateOfWorkoutButton);
    mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutTextView);
    mTimePicker1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutButton);


    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    final Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = t.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = t.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //set the current time into the textview



    mTimePicker1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

}

// updates the date in the TextView
private void updateDisplay() {
        StringBuilder string1 = new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" ");
    mDateDisplay.setText(string1);
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
         new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
         hour = selectedHour;
         minute = selectedMinute;
         updateTimeDisplay();
     }
 };

//set current time into textView
private void updateTimeDisplay() {
     if(hour > 12){
         hour -= 12;
         zone = "PM";
     }
     else
         zone = "AM";

     if(minute >= 10){
     mTimeDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour)
                .append(":").append(minute).append(" ").append(zone));
     }
     else
         mTimeDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour)
                .append(":").append("0").append(minute).append(" ").append(zone));
 }

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, false);
    }
    return null;
}



public void nameOfWorkout(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder nameOfWorkoutAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    nameOfWorkoutAlert.setTitle("Enter a Name for This Workout");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    nameOfWorkoutAlert.setView(input);
    // Prepping the soft keyboard to open with the AlertDialog
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);

    nameOfWorkoutAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      String value = input.getText().toString();
      TextView edit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameOfWorkoutTextView);
      edit.setText(value);
      imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN, 0);
      }
    });

    nameOfWorkoutAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN, 0);
      }
    });
    //alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    nameOfWorkoutAlert.show();

    //Causing the soft keyboard to open with the AlertDialog
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public void typeOfWorkout(View view){
    final String [] items=new String []{"Weight-lifting","Cardio","Mixture"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Today's Workout type");

    builder.setItems(items, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.typeOfWorkoutTextView);
    txt.setText(items[which]);
    }
    });

    builder.show();

}

}
```

Comment: what device are you testing with? The default behavior on the vast majority of devices would close the keyboard for you when the user navigated away.

Answer (score 2):

In your `onPause` you could add the following:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Okay, I created an onPause method, but it's not able to resolve my EditText Object, because it's not in that scope, if I'm using the correct terminology. I'm pretty new to all of this, but I think I need to pass that EdtiText object to the onPause() method? Here's what I have now:

Comment: Oops, sorry, my new code is up in my original post, under UPDATE.

Comment: You should be able to just declare `input` up top with your other Button and TextView and it should work.